# Light affect just one object of your model without using the compositor?

Tags: masking

Is there a easy and fast way to make an area lamp for example affect just one part of your model
I got a model of a hardware with a display and I would like the display to be affected by the area light but not the hardware.

Comment: Separate lighting for different parts of an object and without the Compositor - for this effect?  Was done in 2.77 but should be equally as possible in more recent versions.

Link -

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtkhCKZLZs_Pg21iJJHm5Rc6YJ5i?e=RmAWqD

Comment: You can do stuff like this sometimes.  It's easiest when you can isolate one type of ray to be a sort of 'sentinel' for the behavior you want to trigger, but in this case I'd say the easy and fast solution is to use two render layers and an *Alpha Over* in the compositor.

Answer (score -2):

You could just render them separately. It may or may not take longer since you have to render twice. But since they're separate images, you can change one without affecting the other.

The first render could have just the hardware and the display with no area lamp, or just the hardware if you don't need the shadow of the display cast.

Then on the second render, just the display and the area lamp. If it helps, just put these three objects in different layers and then toggle the render icon at the right side that looks like a picture camera.

Then combine the 2 renders in the Video Sequence Editor as image/image sequence/scene/clip and so on.